# AngularJS: How do I translate this to the 'Angular Way' and using AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

I'm using this form lo do a post request to my node server. Right now it works but I want to translate this to Angular. I've tried ng-file-upload with little success. For some reason the page works perfectly with the plain form but as soon as I try anything fancy with Angular I keep getting 500s from the server.

This is the form that works:

```
<form action="/auth/upload" method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
  <input type="file" name="photo" id="photo" multiple=false>
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

This is my server side code.

```
router.post('/upload', upload.single('photo'), function(req, res, next){
  var bucketName = '..';
  var file = req.file;
  var filename = file.originalname;
  var ext = _.last(filename.split('.'))
  var keyName = uuid.v4() + '.' + ext;
  var url = process.env.AWS_URL + bucketName + '/' + keyName;
  var params = { Bucket: bucketName, Key: keyName, Body: file.buffer, ACL:'public-read' };
  s3.putObject(params, function(err, data) {
    if (err){
      console.log(err)
    }
    else{
      console.log("Successfully uploaded data to myBucket/myKey");
      console.log("The URL is", url);
    }    
  });
res.sendStatus(200);
});
```

The server works nicely with this form, this is why I'm interested in not changing my backend and find a way to adapt angular to translate what my form is doing right now.

Comment: by 'plain form', do you mean form without file upload?

Comment: With that form shown there, which includes file upload, it works perfectly. 'Plain form', is simply without any other code added.

Comment: You can compare the request header and the request payload generated by your plain-form and the corresponding ones generated by Angular using Chrome DevTool.
Then you should be able to understand the problem.
If that doesn't help, please post those data into your question. It would help figure out your problem.